# HTTPS URL Rewrite Rule for Specific Page Using IIS 7.5

Tags: https, url-rewriting, iis-7.5

I am trying to get URL rewrite in IIS 7.5 to redirect to HTTPS for a "single page".
The rest of the domain should remain HTTP.

To do this, I am editing my Web.config file. Can somebody tell me what I am doing
wrong in the below rule:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SpecificRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^register.aspx$" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://mail.domain.org/register.aspx" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

Below is what my URL Rewrite module looks like in IIS 7.5

[image]

thanks much.

Comment: Anybody have an idea here? Or, an appropriate link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are very close, but your redirect will cause infinite loop. Try this:

```
<rule name="SpecificRedirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^register.aspx$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^off$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://mail.domain.org/register.aspx" />
</rule>
```

Let me know if you have to handle multiple domains, then the rule will need more complex rewrite url.

**EDIT:** obviously we need Redirect not Rewrite :)

Comment: Thanks Tomek. I'll give that a go. One more question - is there anything I need to do to "enable" URL rewrite on the production server or is having the code in Web.config all the action that needs to be taken?

Comment: OK, I just tried the above Web.config code. I posted it to our DEV server. Still nothing - stays at HTTP. I wonder if there is a setting in IIS I am neglecting?

Comment: Make sure [URLRewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) module is installed.

Comment: Thanks Tomek. I went to the server and confirmed that URL Rewrite is installed. It is not a default module in IIS 7.5? If it isn't, then AWS must have installed it in the instance I created. Regardless, it is there and the above rule doesn't work. I have done a screen capture of the URL Rewrite UI - maybe you see something I don't? Thanks for your help.

Comment: We need 301 redirect not rewrite, rewrite does its job server site while here obviously we want browser to hit https protocol.

Comment: Thanks Tomek. I have changed <action type="Rewrite" to <action type="Redirect". I have just uploaded the change to the server and it still fails to work. I am not really sure what to try next. Does the uploaded URLRewrite image look right to you? Do you have any ideas as to what I could do to test? Thanks again for your help, seriously appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe try something very basic, it will redirect all to app root, see if that works:
`<rule name="Test">
    <match url=".*" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
</rule>`